# Javascript image 360 view script only working on certain pages

Tags: javascript

On my online shop I have certain products that have a "View 360" button so that you can see part of the product spinning and control it with your mouse.

I have tried to configure this on the website on this page for example:
http://oakandrattan.com/Rattan-Dining-Sets/4-6-or-8-Seater-LA-Round-Table-Set

As you can see when you click on the "View 360" it just displays the first image in the range of images used to create the 360. I believe that there is something wrong with the way I have used the javascript on the page as I have tested it out on a basic test page which can be seen here:
http://oakandrattan.com/spin/test.html

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong on the actual product page.

Thank-you for your help.

Comment: Well, there's an error message in the javascript console that may be more explicit for you than for us... check this before anything

Comment: spin.js isn't loading correctly. it's being returned from the server as an html file. might be an incorrect path or rewrite rule. Try using http://oakandrattan.com/spin/spin/spin.js instead of http://oakandrattan.com/Rattan-Dining-Sets/spin/spin/spin.js?

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you for pointing me in the right direction. I cannot believe I missed this: I didn't put a "/" at the start of the spin.js src meaning it was trying to reach it from the wrong url.

Comment: It says I need to wait 2 days